# Review my very first JS problem - Absolute Begginer

Tags: javascript, algorithm

¡Hello!

I've just joined the blog. I started learning JS last week and I'm thinking about this problem:
I need to know the value of the `x` variable after the function f has been executed.

This is the code:

```
function f(a, b, c, d){
    b = 4.0;
    c = 'A';
    return !(d || (a > 4) && (b < 3.5));
}

var d, c, a, x;

a = true;
c = 7.0;
d = 5;
x = f(d,c,'R',a);
```

I think that, at the end, `x` might be `false` (?)

I know that this looks completely silly compared to many coding issues down there but I'm still starting to crawl. Thanks :)

Comment: open console, paste code, log `x`, ???, PROFIT

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own and tell what you've tried to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any browser console to run these lines of code. Below is a screenshot of the chrome output "false" of your code.
[Chrome developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX1Vt.png)